# Screen Options JavaScript Code

Tags: jquery, wp-admin, javascript, jquery-ui

I want to know, what script drives the "screen options" animation toggle in WordPress.

I'm referring to the options menu that slides out when the admin clicks the "Screen Options" link near the upper right corner of the window in the Post, or Page, or Categories, etc. – and slides back in when the same link is clicked again.

Would appreciate it if someone knowledgeable could show me the exact location of that JavaScript code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in `wp-admin/js/common.js` or `wp-admin/js/common.min.js`:

```
// Scroll into view when focused
$('#contextual-help-link, #show-settings-link').on( 'focus.scroll-into-view', function(e){
    if ( e.target.scrollIntoView )
        e.target.scrollIntoView(false);
});
```

Found with a search for `show-settings-link` in the complete source. :)